# Jenkins Python Print Console Output

Tags: python, linux, selenium, jenkins

Trying to print text "Logged in" in Jenkins through a test case such as:

```
import unittest
from #path.to.methods import method
Class TC1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_tc01(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.chrome()
        driver = method(self.driver)
        driver.login()
        print ("Logged in")
```

In Jenkins my Build Execute Shell Command reads:

```
cd path/to/test
py.test --cov
```

Currently the Jenkins console output does not show the print statement however it does show when I run it on my personal computer

Comment: you may need to flush the output. `sys.stdout.flush()` as jenkins console does whatever it wants.

Comment: Which operating systems are you running?

Comment: I am running jenkins on Linux

Answer (score 4):

Can you add this at the beginning of your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
```

What `-u` does:

```
 python -u
-u     Force  stdin,  stdout  and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems where it matters, also put
       stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.  Note that there is internal buffering  in  xreadlines(),
       readlines()  and  file-object  iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not influenced by this
           option.  To work around this, you will want to use  "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside  a  "while  1:"
           loop.
```

or:

```
import unittest
import sys #<--this 
from #path.to.methods import method
Class TC1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_tc01(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.chrome()
        driver = method(self.driver)
        driver.login()
        print ("Logged in")
        sys.stdout.flush() #<--and this
```